# Is possible to find on SQLAlchemy query level which persons are inside circle with center c =(x,y) and radius=r?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I need to find all Persons which are in radius of some point.
Is possible to find on SQLAlchemy query level which persons are inside circle with center c =(x,y) and radius=r ?

```
class PersonModel(Base):
    x = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    y = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    # other data like name and so on
```

I can easily find all in square or iterate through all and then in python inside for loop eliminate all which are out but I wonder can I eliminate already at query level, it would be faster?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'd need to use `sqlalchemy.func` on some in-database distance function.  Some spatial database backends support distance functions directly, like SpatiaLite and PostGIS, but you'd otherwise need to code up an in-database SQL function to call.  A good example doing this with SQLA for SQLite can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595050/python-sqlalchemy-filter-query-by-great-circle-distance?rq=1).