# How to query with math functions in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a query based on the distance between two geographical points calculated with the Haversine formula. (FYI, I am using Flask.)

This is the method which I have made that is supposed to function as the filter condition in a query:

```
@hybrid_method
def is_nearby(self, latitude, longitude, radius):
    return acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians(self.latitude)) + cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(self.latitude)) * cos(radians(self.longitude) - (radians(longitude)))) * 6371 <= radius
```

But `sqlalchemy.func` doesn't contain any math functions like `acos`, `radians` and `sin` etc. This method doesn't work without these.

I noticed that there's an [extension for that](http://www.sqlite.org/contrib). But how in the heck do I implement that extension (I'm not used to using other programming languages than Python, Javascript etc.) ?

I found [a guide](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Build_SQLite_extension_on_windows), where I had to download a seemingly huge amount of software to get it all working, and I did. But then when I opened the MSYS2 shell and typed in `gcc -fPIC -lm -shared extension-functions.c -o libsqlitefunctions.dll`, I got an error saying `bash: gcc: command not found`. And when I then tried to install MinGW-w64 toolchain with this command:

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo mingw-w64-x86_64-xz mingw-w64-x86_64-lz4`

, it just failed: `Aborted (core dumped)`

**How do I install this extension? And is there optionally a workaround to the installing of this?**

*This question is a follow-up on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820133/how-to-pass-a-model-parameter-in-a-filter-condition-in-sqlalchemy)*

Comment: `sqlalchemy.func` does not contain any functions for that matter, it is a factory for SQL function expressions. You do not really need to install anything, because you can register just about any Python function for use in SQLite, including the math functions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595050/python-sqlalchemy-filter-query-by-great-circle-distance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061014/accessing-table-variables-in-flask-sqlalchemy-query-during-search